# RaspiCam use GPU to stream h.264 video over TCP

Tags: camera, gpu, ffmpeg

Is there a way to stream the 1080 30p video from the RaspiCam over TCP to use it as surveillance camera in common software?

In my case I'm searching for the possibility to stream to my Xeoma server which is using FFmpeg. I know there are how-to's available for setting up FFmpeg on Pi but the rendering is done by the CPU and not GPU so the video resolution and frame-rate is not full HD currently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes;

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 | cvlc -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

http://www.mybigideas.co.uk/RPi/RPiCamera/